# Create new session in JSF 1.2

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I have a login page, after entering the credentials and submitting I am copying the attributes of current session (let's say A) and invalidating it using `((HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false)).invalidate()`.  After that I am creating a new session (let's say B) using `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true)` and setting the attributes back to new session.  This is done to prevent session fixation.

This works fine in JSF 2.0, but in JSF 1.2 after performing above logic and navigating the user, the newly created session is lost (not killed) before RESTORE_VIEW phase and JSF is creating another session (let's say C).  I have a custom `HttpSessionListener` and able to see both B and C.  How are sessions created or handled in JSF 1.2?

Comment: How are you performing the navigation? By a redirect, right?

Comment: Yes, by using `<redirect/>` tag in `faces-config.xml`

Comment: Okay. Is this on exactly the same application server?